# Warning when trying to use Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

Start a React Native project (here I'm using version 0.64.1), install the suggested dependencies for using React Navigation (here I'm using version 5.9.4) (source https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting- started)

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Once that's done, install the drawer dependency and reproduce the Drawer Navigation example at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation.

```
npm install @react-navigation/drawer

import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here it works perfect BUT I always get the following WARN "If you want to use Reanimated 2 then go through our installation steps".

Well, as you can see in this example, I don't use Reanimated 2, at most I install react-native-reanimated as suggested by the documentation.

So why the alert? Everything works fine, but it's annoying to get an alert and not know why. Does it also happen to you? Have you noticed that?

Answer (score 0):

"Drawer now uses Reanimated 2 if available"
you need install:
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.